# Does a rotating DC motor near a TV affects the signals coming in the TV?

Tags: electricity, electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, everyday-life, signal-processing

In my TV cable the signals were quite noisy so i cut the wire and hanged both the wire parallel to each other. Then the signals became very clear and everything was going alright. Once I was performing an experiment with a simple DC motor I found that when the shaft attached in the motor rotates the signals coming in the TV antenna were disturbed. I was surprised. When i held the shaft to stop the motor the signals became normal. Earlier it never happened. The motor was very simple and it worked on 1.5 V DC cell.
There was no connection between the motor and the TV. I am not sure that what is happening, it may be that the rotating  motor would be radiating or releasing signals.[image]

Comment: Your tv is cathode ray tude tv?CRT?

Comment: What sort of wire are you using for your antenna feed?  Most likely there's zero signal getting from your antenna across that "wire hanging parallel" point, so only the section connected to your TV is acting as an antenna in any case.  And most certainly any cheap DC motor will give off RF white noise due to sparking of the contacts.

Answer (score 1):

That is called EMC : [Electromagnetic compatibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_compatibility).

Your DC machine stator is fed through a brush. Since it is rubbing the commutator plates, it can generate sparks, small arcs and so on. Since these phenomena are really fast, they tend to emit electromagnetic radiations in the whole frequency spectrum (see the Fourier transform of a dirac delta function) and sprinkle EM signals in all around them.

Your antenna (and your cathodic screen) may recieve this noise signal, and the original signal is polluted.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my bathroom fan knocking out my tv, electric motors in general produce an electic field that interupts your signal pattern, also yes i am amazed you have a signal at all with the cables like that, its fairly easy to join them strip both ends back join the 2 inner cores in a connector then twist the stranded outer cores together insuring the inner cores dont touch the outer cores